# pygame font Attribute error

Tags: python, pygame

```
import sys, pygame as pg, random




class Game:
    def __init__(self):
         #initialize game window, etc
         pg.init()
         pg.font.init()
         pg.mixer.init()
         self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
         pg.display.set_caption('myFirstGame')
         self.running = True
         self.font_name = pg.font.match_font('calibri')


    def new(self):
        #resets the game
        self.score = 0
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        #game loop
        self.playing = True
        while self.playing:
            self.draw()


    def draw(self):
         #game loop draw
         self.screen.fill(0, 0, 0)

         self.all_sprites.draw(self.screen)
         self.draw_text(str(self.score), 22, white, 800 / 2, 20)
         #after drawing everything, flip the display
         pg.display.flip()



    def draw_text(self, text, size, color, x, y):
        font = pg.font.Font(self.font_name, size)
        text_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
        text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
        self.screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

 g = Game()
 while g.running:
     g.new()
     g.show_go_screen()

 pg.quit()
```

So I am following a tutorial and am getting this error...

AttributeError: module 'pygame.font' has no attribute 'match_font'

I feel the error has to do with the installation of pygame.  I am running python through MSVC and installed Pygame through the View > Other Windows > Python Environments .. I cant seem to get the fonts to work.  I am following a tutorial trying to learn from it and even copy pasted the code that worked for the creator of the tutorial and get the same error.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

BTW... its not the ENTIRE code.. i cut out a lot of the stuff that doesnt have to do with the font.. variables like width, screen, etc are all valid variables with the entire code.  FONT_NAME is defined as 'calibri' in settings.py which is imported with entire code..

Comment: I'm getting a different error (after adding the missing variables) `pygame.error: font not initialized`. Pygame is not initialized because you forgot the parentheses here `pg.init()`. Check out if that fixes your error. If it still doesn't work, you need to post a [minimal, **complete** and **verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: its there on my entire code.. i just omitted it by accident on the post.. let me edit to reflect that so avoid confusion.. same error persists for me in MSVC

Comment: thank you for the reply skrx... i edited the code to reflect a duplication of the error on my end

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. Try to run the program from the command-line. And please post the complete traceback (error message).

Comment: The error seems to be exclusive to MSVC so im thinking there is just something wrong with the way I installed it pygame for that IDE.. so im not sure what to think.  I tried it in a different IDE (Atom 1.28.2) and it worked as intended

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you're following doesn't look very good, a couple of things:

- You don't need to do `pg.font.init()` if you do `pg.init()` ([docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.init))
- If you're going to use a Sysfont (like calibri), you don't need to do `self.font_name = pg.font.match_font('calibri')` and then `pg.font.Font(self.font_name, size)`. Just use [SysFont](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont)
- Where is `self.all_sprites` define? You use it in `draw` but I don't see where is initialize.
- If `new()` resets the game, it does not make much sense call it in the game loop. Also, if `new()` resets the game, why it calls the draw functions?
- [`mixer`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) is for sounds. If you're not going to play any sound, there's no need to initialize it. Also, if you don't want sound delay, you have to initialize it before `pg.init()` and using [`mixer.pre_init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.pre_init) and [`mixer.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init)
- `show_go_screen` method is missing too :/
- The [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) method does not receive (0,0,0), it should be ((0,0,0)) for black.
- In the `draw_text` method, "white" is not a color, it's a variable. You should use `(255,255,255)` instead.

After all of this: The error I have is from the fill function, not from font.

After fixing it, I have an error from that missing variables/methods I pointed before.

After fixing all this. I don't have any error.

If you know spanish, I have a repo with the basics of pygame https://github.com/Patataman/PythonBasic/tree/master/frameworks/pygame. If not, well, maybe you can figure out xD

Comment: the tutorial is good.. i took out a lot of stuff and changed a lot of stuff in order to make it as minimalistic as possible with focus around the error itself.  There are no sounds *YET* .. the 0,0,0 is my mistake and etc.  In the end im not doing a good enough job explaining what my issue is.  all the stuff that is missing, is in my entire code. i just tried to take stuff out there had little to do with the font.. i failed.

Comment: Aaaaahhh that change this a lot xD. I forget to mention, but I test it with Pygame 1.9.4 and I didn't have any problem after fix that things... Maybe the problem is elsewhere in your code

Comment: I used Atom 1.28.2 and it worked.. so it ended up being the MSVC IDE for me... i dont have pygame installed on that IDE thoroughly appparently.. Thank you for your reply :)